# Passing comma separated argument from a command to another one

Tags: macros, etoolbox, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to reduce the redundant lines of code of a custom package.
I have two commands that do nearly the same thing : one is creating a tabular and fills it with lines, and the other one is just generating the lines.

I would like to create a command that calls the other one.

Instead of this :

```
\def\RWAddTableRow#1/#2!{
 & \textbf{#1} \\
 & #2 \\ }

 \newcommand{\RemarksWriterRows}[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
        Remarks :
        \docsvlist{#1}
}


\newcommand{\RemarksWriterFull}[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
        Remarks :
        \docsvlist{#1}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
\def\RWAddTableRow#1/#2!{
 & \textbf{#1} \\
 & #2 \\ }

 \newcommand{\RemarksWriterRows}[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
        Remarks :
        \docsvlist{#1}
}

\newcommand{\RemarksWriterSmall}[1]{
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
        \RemarksWriterRows{\protect \noexpand #1}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

But each time I pass multiple arguments to `\RemarksWriter`, only the first argument is well formatted. The second and third arguments are concatenated...

I call it like this : `\RemarksWriter{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}`

I tried to use `\protect` and `\noexpand`, but each time the arguments are broken... I'm pretty sure there is something with the protection of the arguments. Am I asking too much things to LaTeX ? Or am I misusing something ?
Thank you !

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

EDIT :

Here are the complete code.

Example.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{My}

\begin{document}

Test0.

\medskip

\RemarksWriterSmall{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}

Test1.

\medskip

\RemarksWriterFull{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}

\medskip

Test2.

\medskip

\RemarksWriterSmall{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}

\medskip

Test3.

\end{document}
```

My.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{My}[Test.]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\def\RWAddTableRow#1/#2!{
 & \textbf{#1} \\
 & #2 \\ }

\newcommand{\RemarksWriterRows}[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
        Remarks :
        \docsvlist{#1}
}


\newcommand{\RemarksWriterFull}[1]{
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
        Remarks :
        \docsvlist{#1}
    \end{tabular}
}


\newcommand{\RemarksWriterSmall}[1]{
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
        \RemarksWriterRows{#1}
    \end{tabular}
}
```

As you can see if you compile, the first `\RemarksWriterSmall` (between Test0 and Test1) will make a strange layout, but not the second one (between Test2 and Test3).
I don't know why.

[image: Strange Layout]

Comment: Please provide the minimal document that has this issue, not only fragments

Comment: You're right, after a few tests, I found cases where everything "seems" to work, and other where it didn't work at all. I corrected it and added the best example of strange behavior.... probably because of my misunderstand of LaTeX.

Comment: I think this is a grouping problem: `\renewcommand{\do}` inside the table cell groups will not expand over the table cells

Comment: The reason why it works in the 2nd usage of `\RemarksWriterSmall` is that it has the meaning of `\RWAddTableRow` from the `\RemarksWriterFull`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `\RemarksWriterSmall` does not work in the first case is that it uses `\RemarksWriterRows` inside, there being `\do` redefined in the first table cell. This is a local change only, in the next table cell `\do` has the old meaning of `\noexpand` and not what was expected.

The second usage of `\RemarksWriterSmall` works because it has taken over the global change of `\do` from the `\RemarksWriterFull`, which is a 'bad' idea without grouping.

If the `\do` change should persist in the tabular cells, store the old definition of `\do` with `\let\origdo\do` first, then use a `\gdef\do` in `\RemarksWriterRows` and restore the definition after the `\end{tabular}` with `\let\do\origdo`.

I prefer the `\RemarksWriterFull` version, however.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{My}

\begin{document}

Test0.

\medskip

\meaning\do
\RemarksWriterSmall{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}
\meaning\do
Test1.

\medskip

\meaning\do
\RemarksWriterFull{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}
\meaning\do
\medskip

Test2.

\medskip

\meaning\do
\RemarksWriterSmall{Author1/My remarks, Author2/My other remarks, Author3/Last remarks}
\meaning\do

\medskip

Test3.

\end{document}
```

`My.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{My}[Test.]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\def\RWAddTableRow#1/#2!{%
 & \textbf{#1} \\
 & #2 \\ }

\newcommand{\RemarksWriterRows}[1]{
  \gdef\do##1{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
  Remarks Original:
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}




\newcommand{\RemarksWriterFull}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\RWAddTableRow##1!}
  \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
    Remarks :
    \docsvlist{#1}
  \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
}


\newcommand{\RemarksWriterSmall}[1]{
  \let\origdo\do
    \begin{tabular}{p{7cm} p{10cm}}
      \RemarksWriterRows{#1}
    \end{tabular}
  \let\do\origdo
}
```

[image]

Comment: A better variant might be using `expl3` features!

Comment: @Metalman: `\let` is some kind of Black TeX Magic ;-)

Comment: Whoa. Thank you. I'm still a learner on LaTeX.
I saw things with "\let" and co, but I was pretty lost.

I'm still interested to know : why the "\do" changed of meaning in the Full and not the Small ? When did it was "activated" ? (I want to see the debug/traces of latex, but I don't know how to do it)
How/Where exactly the lines are copied ? By which command ?

To be honest : I copy/paste this code, and I tried to understand it... but as you can see : I didn't understand it.

Comment: @Metalman: `\renewcommand` does change the meaning of a macro only in the current TeX group. A table cell is such a group, i.e. the redefined meaning of a certain macro is lost after the `&` which starts the next table cell. `\docsvlist` splits your comma-separated list according to your `\RWAddTableRow` macro applying the `\do` command, i.e. using `\do` for each element of the list. This works in the `Small` version only for the first table cell, then `\do` having the meaning of `\RWAddTableRow` is 'forgotten` and the rest of the list is squeezed into the first table cell of the next row.

Comment: Okay, I need to read more on the TeX group... I was convinced it was linked with the environment (I quickly checked the RobustDeclaration and others, without deep reading), and it's even more complex than what I expected.

Thank you a lot ! (I don't have enough reputation for putting a "+1", but I'll do when I'll be able !)