# Table from csv file with two header rows

Tags: tables, csv

I have multiple `csv` files to read and create a table with one or two headerlines. (parameters/units) I would like to use two header lines from this files using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. Can anyone help me? It would be enough to give a parameter containing the number of header lines to extract.

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
                %skip first n=1,
                col sep=comma, % the seperator in our .csv file
                every head row/.style={before row={\toprule}, after row={\midrule}},
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},              ]{test.csv}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package ? It's parsing CSV naturally.

I tried it there to produce a table, but not with a csv file : [Passing comma separated argument from a command to another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388363/passing-comma-separated-argument-from-a-command-to-another-one)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about CSV files  and `pgfplotstable` specifically.